# Android php connection not working

Tags: android, mysql

**ANDROID CODE**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.lpu.delight.lovelysweets.R;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddNewItem extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_item);
        EditText proname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.adduprice);
        EditText  unitprice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addpnameet);

        final String PName = proname.getText().toString();
        final String UPrice = unitprice.getText().toString();
        Button btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbtninsert);

        btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert.php");

                try
                {
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pname",PName));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uprice", UPrice));
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**INSERT.PHP CODE**

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "toor";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("android_api",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");


//retrieve the data
$pnm = $_POST['pname'];
$pp = $_POST['uprice'];


mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tblproduct (pname,uprice) VALUES('$pnm', '$pp', NOW())");

mysql_close($dbhandle);

?>
```

**NOT WORKING NOTHING HAPPENING PLEASE HELP**

as I am running its not printing the toast message too. Please help me whats wrong in it in php file the variable is pname and uprice but still its not executing try block.

Comment: please post logcat .you should get some logs. it is possible you fall in catch before reach Toast show.then you should get error by this line "e.printStackTrace()"

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are missing one parameter in `INTO`

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tblproduct (pname,uprice) VALUES('$pnm', '$pp')") or die(mysql_error());
```

;//values are 3 parameters and insert into table have two columns

Comment: Thanks bro for looking into matter

Comment: But still after adding mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tblproduct (pname,uprice) VALUES('$pnm', '$pp')");

Comment: did you echo the data coming to php is it coming properly

Comment: yes bro i echoed the data is being fetched can you joing me on gtak abhigyan17@gmail.com

Comment: check new edit and add replace the querry it will able to print the error if it in sql querry

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your SQL Query, one parameter is missing in your INTO... you are trying to set 3 values and only have 2 table columns defined:

```
INSERT INTO tblproduct (pname,uprice,MISSING_PARAM) VALUES('$pnm', '$pp', NOW())
```

Also, why don't you take a look at okHTTP Library to handle HTTP connections in an easiest way:
http://square.github.io/okhttp/